# Where to find quality audio samples for looping

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, openal, caf

I am working on a musical instrument app for iPhone and need sample sounds that I can use for the various wind instruments. I'll be using OpenAL with looping, so a 1 second sample that is spot-on in-tune and without vibrato or other variation is essential.

My question is: Where can I find audio samples that are, or can be converted to .CAF format for looping play? Need these to be "realistic" sounding, not electronic sounding. Not looking for freebie, looking for professional quality.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the command for converting to CAF format:

```
/usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 myaudiofile.wav myaudiofile.caf;
```

Regarding finding samples, there's a ton out there. Search Google with "free audio samples".

Magazines like [Sound On Sound](http://www.soundonsound.com/) and [Computer Music](http://www.musicradar.com/computermusic) will often have deals. Although sometimes you'll need to buy the magazine, or be a subscriber. They do lots of reviews of commercial sample CDs. Often these are quite reasonably priced (e.g. $50).

As with everything, the key is to check the license carefully to make sure it's full use and that you can redistribute in your app. That also applies to samples that you can download for free.

Comment: Converting the audio to .CAF is not an issue. Already doing that, but thanks anyway. It's the clean, loop-able and pitch-specific sample sounds that I'm not finding. All the "free audio samples", etc... are typically not appropriate for tight "endless" looping.

Comment: Checkout Apple Loops on Logic or Garageband. Also, tools like Stylus RMX and Recycle will help with loops. If you source non "loop ready" samples, you'll need to import them into Recycle or a DAW tool to trim them

Comment: ps. you'll probably find the Sound On Sound forums to be abundant with info on this sort of thing. Much more helpful than Stack Overflow as it's really an audio issue rather than development